# Using questionmark (?) to check if variable is null or undefined - bad practice?

Tags: typescript

I heard from a colleague that it is bad practice to use a question mark to check if a variable is null or undefined and in the same turn call a property / method on this. For example.

```js
let text = null;
if(new Date().getDay > 3) {
  text = 'some text';
}
console.log(text?.toLowerCase())
```

I see that the console logs undefined, which is probably a unintended behaviour. But can somebody give me a source why this is bad practice? I cant find anything on the internet.

Comment: "*I heard from a colleague [...] can somebody give me a source why this is bad practice?*" Umm, your colleague, perhaps?

Comment: Check out the docs for optional chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: I don’t think this is bad practice. It definitely requires some finesse to make sure you’re not hiding any unintended side effects (if that’s possible). But it’s something I have used regularly.

Comment: "But can somebody give me a source" — Questions asking for external resources are off-topic here.

Comment: "why this is bad practice" — That's a matter of opinion (which is off-topic here).

Comment: "*I see that the console logs undefined, which is probably a unintended behaviour*" very much intended and as per spec.

Comment: @Ironolife thanks, didnt know it is called optional chaining.

Comment: @VLAZ no i mean unintended for my code. Not for the spec.

Comment: It's exactly how optional chaining is supposed to behave. If that's not what you intended for the code to do, that's not a problem with optional chaining. Computers do what you tell them to, not what you want them to.